# Android TTS voices

Tags: android, api, text-to-speech

I have TTS working on my apps. But the voice is really harsh. I know it can be changed by the user, but has anyone come across any nice software you can integrate into the app itself, so it seems pre-installed to the user?

Comment: seems to me it would be a pretty thankless job to do that, you'd never be able to please everyone... if you just let the user replace the default voice with something nice (I forget which one I bought, but it was worth it) the user will be happier... just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd be open to it, but maybe a cloud based solution with multiple voices would work for you? Again, I'm not too familiar with it, but iSpeech appears to have an Android SDK and allows direct API access for text-to-speech and ASR.

If  you end up trying it, let me know how it is.

Found their website: http://www.ispeech.org/developers